# The closed unit ball of a normed space X is compact iff X is finite-dimensional

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, compactness

I have a question about this theorem:
" The closed unit ball of a normed space X  is compact iff X  is finite-dimensional."

if I  take (R,+,.,Q)
R is a infinite dimensional vector space when we take rational numbers set as a field. but if we take Euclid norm. we know from Heine-Borel Theorem the closed unit ball in R is compact.
this contadicts the theory.

There must be something wrong with my example, but I want to know what it is?

Comment: The theorem is about real or complex vector spaces.

Comment: Scrutinize a proof of this theorem, with your "counterexample" in hand, to detect the flaw.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I don't Know. in the book he write if X a normed vector space. sometimes he take the field as complex numbers. is this theorem is speacial for complex vector space?

Comment: Which book is that?

Comment: functional analysis but it is turkish not English

Comment: You can find the proof for X infinite-dimensional normed vector space then the unit ball is not compact in Linear Functional Analysis by Rynne and Youngson. Basically you can construct a sequence that doesn't have a convergent subsequence based on Riesz's Lemma. And it is true for whatever field $\mathbb{F}$.
In your case I don't understand what $(R,+,.,Q)$ is.

Comment: @rcescon R is a finite dimensional  vector space when we take the field as R. but when we take the field as Q rational numbers set then R is infinite dimensional vector space.

Comment: @A12345 Then if you consider the set of rational numbers as field the result doesn't hold since $\mathbb{F}$ is either the reals or complex numbers.

Comment: @rcescon thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your space is not a normed space. A normed space is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, or sometimes over $\mathbb{C}$ (which is not that different from $\mathbb{R}$ in this context) with some additional structure. By definition.

But not over $\mathbb{Q}$. That would have to be an explicit assumption, $\mathbb{Q}$ behaves very differently from the other two (topological) fields. For example over $\mathbb{Q}$ no finite dimensional ball is compact, while some infinite dimensional are (but not all).

While $\mathbb{C}$ is quite similar to $\mathbb{R}$ in this context. In fact, $\mathbb{C}$-normed spaces are pretty much $\mathbb{R}$-normed spaces of even dimension.

Comment: I didn't know that. I thought that when we define a norm function on any vector space, then this becomes a normed space. the book I'm studying from doesn't mention such this condition. thank you.

Comment: @A12345 yes, this is mandatory. It might be a mistake in the book.

Comment: yes, I think it is a mistake. thank you.